# Birthday Countdown

Tags: javascript, html, date, time

Im trying to write a program where the user enters their birthday and a countdown timer appears and counts down the months days hours and seconds until their birthday.  Right now it is not not working and any help would be great! Thanks!

```
<body>
    <script>

        var end = new Date();
        document.getElementById("myDate").value = end;
        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var _month = _day * 30;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {


            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
                return;
            }

            var months = Math.floor(distance / _month);
            var days = Math.floor((distance % _month) / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = months + 'months ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += days + 'days ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

    </script>

        Enter your birthday:
        <br>
        <input type="date" id="myDate">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" onclick="showRemaining()" value="Enter">


    <div id="countdown"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail than *'it is not working'*?   What, specifically, is happening?  How is that different from your expected result?

Comment: When I enter my birthday it says EXPIRED, which means it thinks the date is in the past or not valid, but it is not coming up with the countdown timer which is what I want it to do.  I tried entering a date way in the future and it still says expired.

Comment: Your `distance` variable never references the entered birthday.  The calculation `distance = end - now` is only evaluating dates set when the page loaded, and when the user clicked the button.  It's not using the birthday anywhere in the calculation.

Comment: Your countdown will be inaccurate as months don't all have 30 days and if the host is set to observe daylight saving, not all days are 24 hours long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code as identified in other answers, I'll paraphrase:

1. The script runs before the elements exist in the DOM, so attempts to reference them return *null* and you'll get errors attempting to set its properties.
2. *end* is set as the page loads, so it's always in the past in respect to when the function runs, so `end - now` is either 
   zero (probably initially) or negative (more than 1 millisecond after assigning to *end*).
3. The button will allow multiple instance of *setInterval* to be running, so you'll get some pretty confusing results since they're all trying to set the value of *countdown*
4. The calculation is flawed as there aren't exactly 30 days in every month, nor 24 hours in every day if the host observes daylight saving. Fixing that isn't hard, but I'm not going to fix it here.
5. Don't use input type Date, support is patchy. You can test for support and handle cases where it isn't, but it's all a bit much for this exercise.

So, don't start the timer until the button is pressed (or some other event after the page is loaded), stop any timer that is currently running and reset *end* at the same time.

Note that *setInterval* will drift as it doesn't run at exactly every second, so every now and then it will skip two seconds. Also, invalid date input should be dealt with. Both can be fixed, but out of scope here. ;-)

```js
// Don't set the value for end until the button is pressed.
var end; // = new Date();
         // document.getElementById("myDate").value = end;

// Also need a global timer reference so it can be cancelled when required   
var timer;

// Since listener is attached by addEventListener, event will only be passed
// if the call comes from the button
function showRemaining(event) {
  // Function to cancel the timer
  function stopTimer(){
    if (timer) {
   clearInterval(timer);
   end = timer = null;
 }
  }
  
  // Keep these local
  var _second = 1000;
  var _minute = _second * 60;
  var _hour = _minute * 60;
  var _day = _hour * 24;
  var _month = _day * 30;
  
  // If click came from the button or timer isn't set, restart the timer
  if (event || !timer) {
    stopTimer();
 timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
  }

  // Get the current date
  var now = new Date();
  
  // Get the value of countdown and parse it, see parsing function
  // If end isn't set, set it
  if (!end) end = parseDateDMY(document.getElementById("myDate").value);
  var distance = end - now;
 
  // If gone past end, stop the timer 
  if (distance < 0) {
    stopTimer();
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

  } else {
    var months = Math.floor(distance / _month);
    var days = Math.floor((distance % _month) / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    // Write the time remaining directly to the element
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = months + 'months ' +            
                                                  days + 'days ' +
              hours + 'hrs ' +
              minutes + 'mins ' +
              seconds + 'secs';
  }
}

// No need to do this, wait for button click
// timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000); 

// Parse date string in format d/m/y
function parseDateDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Add listener to button
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click',showRemaining,false);
}
```

```html
Enter your birthday:<br>
<input type="text" id="myDate" value="21/6/2016">d/m/y<br>
<input type="button" id="startButton" value="Start counting"><br>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made quite a few mistakes,

1. The script loads before the elements load. So, it does not work properly. Always incude scripts at the last or use `window.onload = (function() { [Your code] }());`. This executes only after the dom loads.
2. The `setInterval` function must always execute only if "not EXPIRED!". Keep it within the function so it only runs again if the countdown must go on.
3. The main problem, you were comparing date strings to 0. You can rather use 
   `Date.now()` which returns the total milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970. And use `Date("User Input String which you provided")` to get the total milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970 till that date and see the difference which is very accurate.

I recommend using separate input boxes or a more formatted input. Read more about these [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Also try using 'buttonElement.addEventListener("click", showRemaining);`.

This should work:

```
<body>
<script>
    var end = new Date();
    document.getElementById("myDate").value = end;
    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var _month = _day * 30;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = Date.now(); //CHANGE
        end = new Date(document.getElementById("myDate").value); //CHANGE
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
            return;
        }

        var months = Math.floor(distance / _month);
        var days = Math.floor((distance % _month) / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = months + 'months ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += days + 'days ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000); //CHANGE
    }
</script>

<!-- CHANGE -->
Enter your birthday:
<br />
<input type="date" id="myDate">
<br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="showRemaining()" value="Enter">
```

Comment: Re #3, where? In the OP, *now* and *end* are Date objects. The value of *myDate* is never read, only set (before it exists).

Answer (score 0):

This snippet fixes your issue. The issue was two-fold.

1. `document.getElementById("myDate").value = end;` This statement is reversed. You want need the value of the field to be put into `end`. This statement also executes immediately, which is of no use. This has been replaced by two things (1) the `initDate` function, to make the date field have an initial value (if that's what you were trying to do), and (2) the event listener on the button. This way, when the user has selected a date and clicks the button, you know that a value has been set, and can confidently start the timer.
2. Dates. The date value given by the `input` you have is in the format `YYYY-mm-dd`, which needs to be `split()` on the hyphens to create a `new Date()` correctly. The `Date` library can be tricky to work with. When creating dates it can be hard to determine if they're going to be UTC or local. And that issue can screw you up pretty easily, so watch that.

This code should be what you're looking for and should help clarify some of the points you may not have understood when writing the original code. It's not perfect necessarily (due to the fact that a month is hardcoded in as 30 days), but it depends on what you are looking for. Let me know if you have any other questions.

```js
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var _month = _day * 30;
var timer;

initDate();

document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
  var splitValues = document.getElementById("myDate").value.split('-');
  var end = new Date(splitValues[0], splitValues[1] - 1, splitValues[2]);
  clearInterval(timer);
  showRemaining(end);
  timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000, end);
});

function showRemaining(end) {
  var now = new Date();
  var distance = end - now;
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
    return;
  }

  var months = Math.floor(distance / _month);
  var days = Math.floor((distance % _month) / _day);
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = months + 'months ';
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += days + 'days ';
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
}

function initDate() {
  var defaultDate = new Date();
  var month;
  if(defaultDate.getMonth() + 1 > 9) {
    month = "" + (defaultDate.getMonth() + 1);
  } else {
    month = '0' + (defaultDate.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("myDate").value = defaultDate.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + defaultDate.getDate();
}
```

```html
<input id="myDate" type="date">
<button id="startButton">Start Countdown</button>
<div id="value"></div>
<div id='countdown'></div>
```

I have included the "more accurate" version below, since it was easy to change.

```js
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

initDate();

document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
  var splitValues = document.getElementById("myDate").value.split('-');
  var end = new Date(splitValues[0], splitValues[1] - 1, splitValues[2]);
  clearInterval(timer);
  showRemaining(end);
  timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000, end);
});

function showRemaining(end) {
  var now = new Date();
  var distance = end - now;
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
    return;
  }

  var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ' days ';
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + ' hrs ';
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + ' mins ';
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + ' secs';
}

function initDate() {
  var defaultDate = new Date();
  var month;
  if (defaultDate.getMonth() + 1 > 9) {
    month = "" + (defaultDate.getMonth() + 1);
  } else {
    month = '0' + (defaultDate.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("myDate").value = defaultDate.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + defaultDate.getDate();
}
```

```html
<input id="myDate" type="date">
<button id="startButton">Start Countdown</button>
<div id="value"></div>
<div id='countdown'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So how would I get it to be more accurate and not have months be hardcoded as 30 days? Thanks again!

Comment: I would add some logic that would add a month only when the date chosen is (1) in the next month and (2) has a greater date than the current date (meaning, for example, today is the 14th and the date of the birthday is the 16th). We think of months that way. Feb 14th is one month away from Mar 14th, despite the number of days being less than any other 14th-to14th set. This means that you will need to change the logic for calculating the numbers for each item, possibly quite a bit.

Comment: This all depends on the application of what you're doing. Many libraries (like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/months/)) just use 30 days, so you're probably fine with what you've got. If you want to be **really** accurate, then drop off the months and just do days, hours, minutes, seconds. But it's just a birthday countdown, so I imagine none of this specificity really matters.

Comment: @jpreston94—if you want a more accurate difference, see [*Converting a date from DD-MM-YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY in Javascript and finding the difference*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880064/converting-a-date-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-finding-the-di/24890372#24890372).