# Time Elapsed Calculation from form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, elapsedtime

I'm working on a time elapsed calculator were the user enters in a month, day, and year. From their input and the current date, I want to calculate how many days are in between and then display how many years, months, and days have elapsed. I started by making a form with three input values of "month" , "day" , and "year". I then started on the script:

```
function timeElapsed() {
       var timeMonth = document.getElementById("month");
       var timeDay = document.getElementById("day");
       var timeYear = document.getElementById("year");
       var currentDate = new Date();
       var elapsed = 
       document.getElementById("timeElapsed").innerHTML = elapsed;
   }
       //Event Listener
       var submitButton= document.getElementById("sButton");
    if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", timeElapsed, false);
    } else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
        submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", timeElapsed);
    }
```

Obviously as you can tell I kind of stopped because I'm stumped on where to go from here. This is a lab in school for me and I just want to understand how to do it. My teacher mentioned *"Note that your program must include code to convert day values in excess of 31 into months, and months in excess of 12 into years."* and I am actually totally confused but understands what he means. It's just actually understanding how to actually do this. It's a web class and it is very hard to understand from just a textbook. I've looked a bit online but I haven't found anything that was useful for my situation. If you can help me out, thank you so much.

Comment: You can start by creating a date from `new Date(year, month-1, day)`, then get the difference as shown here: [*Converting a date from DD-MM-YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY in Javascript and finding the difference*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880064/converting-a-date-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-finding-the-di/24890372#24890372). Note that you probably should zero the hours for *currentDate*, then round to whole days to accommodate possible daylight saving issues (or use all UTC methods).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `example` you can use to calculate Date difference

```js
function get(ID){
  return document.getElementById(ID);
}

function calculateDiff(){
  var FromYear  = get('FromYear').value;
  var FromMonth = get('FromMonth').value;
  var FromDay  = get('FromDay').value;

  var ToYear  = get('ToYear').value;
  var ToMonth  = get('ToMonth').value;
  var ToDay  = get('ToDay').value;
 
  var date1  = new Date(FromYear,FromMonth,FromDay);   /*Create Date Object From date*/
  var date2  = new Date(ToYear,ToMonth,ToDay);         /*Create Date Object To date*/
  var diff  = new Date(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

  get('ResultYear').value  = diff.getUTCFullYear()-1970;  /*Calculate year difference*/
  get('ResultMonth').value = diff.getUTCMonth();          /*Count month difference*/
  get('ResultDay').value   = diff.getUTCDate()-1;         /*Count day difference*/
}

calculateDiff();

var calculate = get('calculate');

calculate.onclick = function(){
  calculateDiff();
}
```

```css
table input{
  width: 60px;
}
button{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>YYYY</th>
      <th>MM</th>
      <th>DD</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>FROM</th>
      <td><input  id="FromYear"  placeholder="YYYY" value="2017"></td>
      <td><input  id="FromMonth" placeholder="MM" value="3"></td>
      <td><input  id="FromDay"   placeholder="DD" value="18"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>TO</th>
      <td><input  id="ToYear"  placeholder="YYYY" value="2017"></td>
      <td><input  id="ToMonth" placeholder="MM" value="3"></td>
      <td><input  id="ToDay"   placeholder="DD" value="29"></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">
        <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>RESULT</th>
       <td><input  id="ResultYear"  placeholder="YYYY" value=""></td>
       <td><input  id="ResultMonth" placeholder="MM" value=""></td>
       <td><input  id="ResultDay"   placeholder="DD" value=""></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `javascript` you can get current date as

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; // as it starts from 0
var currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
```

After getting values from your input date fields you need to do some basic mathematical operations like

```
if(currentMonth < inputMonth) {
  monthBetween = inputMonth - currentMonth;
} else if(currentMonth > inputMonth) {
  monthBetween = currentMonth - inputMonth;
} else {
  monthBetween = 0;
}
```

Here is some sample code you can play around and learn from. https://jsfiddle.net/8pd5f3pe/1/